# Manual (or examples) of r.ros, r.spreadpath and r.spread in GRASS

Tags: raster, grass-gis

you can report me references or applications for use of the following modules (GRASS): 
- **r.ros**, 
- **r.spreadpath**, 
- **r.spread**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Spread** distance is an estimate of the distance field from one or more target cells, such that the distances are routed through the grid lattice (see below). It's calculated iterative, in a way that minimizes the distance field, i.e. shorter routes are sought in each iteration until no shorter route between each grid cell and their nearest target cell can be found.

Before [Shih and Wu](http://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~manzaner/Download/IAD/Shih_Wu_04.pdf) (2003) published their extremely efficient and accurate 4-pass Euclidean distance transform method, **Spread** was the dominant method for estimating distances on a raster in GIS. These days, **Spread** distance isn't used for estimating Euclidean distance (including raster buffering operations) in GIS so much. However, because its iterative approach is conducive to an anisotropic distance calculation, the **Spread** algorithm is still widely used for performing **least-cost pathway analysis**. Shih and Wu's method, while faster and more accurate, is useless for estimating a directionally dependent or cost-factor dependent distance. The **Spread** algorithm also provides the opportunity to calculate the 'back-link' for each cell, essentially equivalent to the D8 flow-direction grid in flow path analysis. In this way, it is possible to identify the 'distance watersheds' that connect each cell in the grid to it's nearest target and to trace individual least-cost pathways for any location to a target. Since least-cost analysis tends to find itself applied in all sorts of spatial optimization problems, the **Spread** tool is still very relevant today.

[image]

[image]

If you're looking for an academic reference for the **Spread** algorithm then I should think Chase (1984) and Rothermel (1983) would be good starting places. If you're just looking for a user reference then the GRASS user manual (http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.spread.html) is the place to start.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
PS: There are examples of using these modules to analyze the evolution of fire?

Comment: I'm happy to help.

Comment: @GiuseppeMorone Yes, fire modelling is perfectly suited to an application of the Spread algorithm since it can be viewed as a special type of least-cost optimization analysis. The anisotropy in this case would be the result of the heterogeneity in fuel availability, wind patterns, and terrain (e.g. fires tend to move upslope), among other factors I'm sure. I won't claim to be an expert in fire modelling though!

Comment: Perfect. Can you give me a reference or a search (a link) that shows the application of these modules in GRASS? 
Thanks for your help. 

PS: I apologize for my English.

Comment: If you're looking for an academic reference for the algorithm then I should think Chase (1984) and Rothermel (1983) would be good starts, but if you're just looking for a user reference then the GRASS user manual http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.spread.html  Is the place to start.

Comment: You can find an animated use here: "GIS-based fire spread modeling" - http://geospatial.ncsu.edu/osgeorel/fire-spread.html